# How to make x and y, which stand after the vertical line, have the same size as the small \psi and x, which stand in \partial

Tags: scaling

```tex
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\omega) = \left.{\psi}\right|_{\omega=0} +
 \omega \cdot 
 \underbrace {\left.\dfrac{d\psi}{d\omega}\right|_{\omega=0} }_{\left.\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\right|_{\substack{{x =0} \\ {y=0}}}} \,+ \,\dfrac{\omega^2}{2} \,\cdot\, \underbrace {\left.\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d\omega \, d\omega}\right|_{\substack{\omega=0}}}_{\left.\frac{\partial \psi^2}{\partial x \partial x}\right|_{\substack{x=0 \\ y=0 }}} + \ldots +
   \dfrac{\omega^p}{p!} \cdot \dfrac{d^p\psi}{d\omega \cdot \ldots \cdot d\omega}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You can safety add line breaks in your code to make it clearer (but do not leave empty lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than miniaturize the arguments of the `\substack` directives, I would *increase* the size of the associated fraction expressions, by using `\tfrac` instead of `\frac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{Before}
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\omega) = \left.{\psi}\right|_{\omega=0} +
 \omega \cdot 
 \underbrace {\left.\dfrac{d\psi}{d\omega}\right|_{\omega=0} }_{\left.\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\right|_{\substack{{x =0} \\ {y=0}}}} \,+ \,\dfrac{\omega^2}{2} \,\cdot\, \underbrace {\left.\dfrac{d^2\psi}{d\omega \, d\omega}\right|_{\substack{\omega=0}}}_{\left.\frac{\partial \psi^2}{\partial x \partial x}\right|_{\substack{x=0 \\ y=0 }}} + \ldots +
   \dfrac{\omega^p}{p!} \cdot \dfrac{d^p\psi}{d\omega \cdot \ldots \cdot d\omega}
\end{equation*}

\medskip
\textcolor{red}{After}
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\omega) = \psi\bigr|_{\omega=0} +
 \omega \cdot 
  {\underbrace {\frac{d\psi}{d\omega}\biggr|_{\omega=0} }%
 _{\tfrac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{\substack{x =0\\y=0 }}}} 
+
\frac{\omega^2}{2} \cdot 
  {\underbrace{\frac{d^2\psi}{d\omega\,d\omega}\biggr|_{\omega=0}}%
 _{\tfrac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x\,\partial x}\Bigr|_{\substack{x=0 \\ y=0 }}}} 
+ \dots +
\frac{\omega^p}{p!} \cdot 
\frac{d^p\psi}{d\omega \ldots d\omega}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX use 4 math styles: `\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`. The smallest is `\scriptscriptstyle`.

`\substack`, like the `subarray` environment use `\scriptstyle`. As a workaround, force `\scriptscriptstyle` inside:

```tex
\substack{\scriptscriptstyle x =0 \\ \scriptscriptstyle y=0}
```